# Raspbian Spin Docker Container with MySQL

Tags: mysql, docker, raspberry-pi3, raspbian

I'm trying to spin up a container on my raspberry pi 3. The container has a MySQL server that is giving me some trouble when I try to spin up.

`$ docker-compose up > /dev/null &`

```
$ Building mysql
ERROR: Service 'mysql' failed to build: no matching manifest for unknown in 
the manifest list entries
```

The yml file looks like this

```
version: '2'
services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.myapiapp
    links:
      - mail
      - mysql
      - memcached

    ...

    mysql:
      build:
        context: docker/mysql/
        #dockerfile: MySQL-5.7.Dockerfile
        dockerfile: MariaDB-Latest.DockerFile
      ports:
        - 13306:3306
      volumes_from:
        - storage
      env_file:
        - etc/environment.yml
        - etc/environment.myapiapp.yml
```

`docker/mysql/MySQL-5.7.Dockerfile` looks like this

```
FROM mysql:5.7
ADD conf/mysql-docker.cnf /etc/mysql/conf.d/z99-docker.cnf
```

`docker/mysql/MariaDB-Latest.DockerFile` looks like this

```
FROM mariadb:latest
ADD conf/mysql-docker.cnf /etc/mysql/conf.d/z99-docker.cnf
```

`$ docker -v`

```
Docker version 18.09.0, build 4d60db4
```

Answer (score 2):

[MariaDB](http://soaphub.org/imagehub/?q=mariadb&n=library&o=1) and [MySQL](http://soaphub.org/imagehub/?q=mysql&n=library&o=1) don't have Docker images for ARM. Only MariaDB has ARM64 which isn't what the Raspberry pi uses as a CPU.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I noticed other people have this issue with windows/linux images, so this makes sense here too.

Comment: Are there any alternatives to use?

Answer (score 0):

You can use postgres instead as an alternative to mysql as it is available for raspberry pi with 32 bit architecture.

Here's the dockerhub [link](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres).

or If you really want to use mysql, you can build it by yourself using docker file by taking ubuntu or any other os as base image.